# summarizing variables with similar but not identical x-values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset with three repeats. I want to plot the mean Y variable for each X variable. However, my x-values are not identical.

Here is a small example of what I mean:

```
Time Value repeat_name
0    5     repeat1
0    5     repeat2
0    5     repeat3
3.1  7     repeat1
3.25 8     repeat2
3    9     repeat3
6.2  5     repeat1
6.5  5     repeat2
6    5     repeat3
9.3  5     repeat1
9.75 5     repeat2
9    5     repeat3
```

Now I was hoping there would be some way I could bin the time and then put all values that match the binned value inside

so I have the following bins:

```
Time
0-4 (values (5,5,5,7,8,9))
4-8 (values (5,5,5))
8-12 (values (5,5,5))
```

and that I could then take the mean of those bins and plot a histogram with ggplot. I am however, not sure how I would achieve my goal.

I am also not sure if there is a better approach to this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Time would be your x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to plot the mean of a variable based on the grouping of another variable, a histogram is not the proper chart, given that a histogram reflects counts of observations within a bin range.

As Tjebo points out above, ggplot has some stat functions that can compute summary statistics on data.

The stat_summary_bin() function can compute summary statistics across binned ranges. To compute the mean of the bins of `Time` from above you can use the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y = Value)) +
  stat_summary_bin(geom = "point", 
                   fun.y = mean, 
                   fun.ymin = NULL, 
                   fun.ymax= NULL, 
                   breaks=seq(0, 12,by = 4))
```

where `mean` is the summary function computed on the data and the bin ranges are set using `seq(0, 12, by = 4)` to match the bin ranges from above. It is also possible to provide a default bin width using the `binwidth` argument or the  number of bins using the `bins` argument.
[image]
Alternatively, you can calculate group means with a dplyr::case_when() statement to generate a grouping variable, group the data frame by that newly created grouping variable and finally summarize the values.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    group_var = case_when(
      Time >=0 & Time < 4 ~ 1,
      Time >= 4 & Time < 8 ~ 2,
      Time >= 8 & Time < 12 ~ 3
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarize(grouped_mean = mean(Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just some suggestions. The binning is of course the challenge. You can either round, or create cuts. It depends totally on what you want to show.

I will show two options, one with `plyr::round_any`, the other using `cut`

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- read_csv("Time, Value, repeat_name
0,    5,     repeat1
0,    5,     repeat2
0,    5,     repeat3
3.1,  7,     repeat1
3.25, 8,     repeat2
3,    9,     repeat3
6.2,  5,     repeat1
6.5,  5,     repeat2
6,    5,     repeat3
9.3,  5,     repeat1
9.75, 5,     repeat2
9,    5,     repeat3")

foo %>% 
  mutate(time_round = plyr::round_any(Time, 5)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time_round, Value)) +
  stat_summary() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =  c(0, NA))
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

```r
foo %>% 
  mutate(time_cut = cut(Time, c(-Inf,4,8,Inf))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time_cut, Value)) +
  stat_summary() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =  c(0, NA))
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Also worth noting that since ggplot2 v3.3.0 there are binned scales, i.e. `scale_x_binned(breaks = c(2, 4, 8))`

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for pointing this out. Have to add this to my vocabulary :)